# iPhone - following -L not found

Tags: iphone, xcode, warnings

I am trying to modify an old app and when I build it gives me the following 2 warnings:

> ld: warning: directory
>   '/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator3.0.sdk/usr/lib'
>   following -L not found

and

> ld: warning: directory
>   '/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS3.0.sdk/usr/lib'
>   following -L not found

Anyone knows where this comes from?

I am using xCode 3.2.5

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, if the text of the error message is to be believed:

```
ld: warning: directory [...] not found
```

...it says that a directory was not found. If you google for compiler flags, you'll see that `-L` is for specifying additional library search path directories. So the directory it mentions in the error doesn't exist.

You need to look in the project settings somewhere where the given folder is specified -- it will need updating to the current directory for the current version of the SDK you have.

Comment: Thanks. It was a reference to a 3.0 directory left from the old xCode.